# Emulator expo No apps connected. Sending "reload" to all React Native apps failed

Tags: android, expo, emulation

I have a problem with my emulator and Expo using a android build. It turns out that before, when I opened the dev build, it worked perfectly on my emulator, but suddenly it stopped working. Now I open it with **`npx expo start`** and the letter 'a' and the application open, but when I reload, I get the warning: "No apps connected. Sending 'reload' to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB." and the app doesn't update. I already tried the command **`adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`** but it didn't work. Please help.

¿Ha sido útil esta conversación hasta ahora?

i try this  but  don't work tcp:8081 tcp:8081